# C++ Remove object from vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to remove an object of class `Attack` from vector called "movelist" that is inside the player class.  I tried to use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) and got this error:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Attack' and 'const Attack')
```

Any suggestions?

```
void Player::del_attack(Attack a1)
{
   Attack to_rmv=a1;
   movelist.erase(std::remove(movelist.begin(), movelist.end(), to_rmv), movelist.end());
}
```

I've got

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
```

Comment: How is defined your vector?

Comment: I mean the variable

Comment: vector<Attack> movelist;

Comment: and other operations on that vector works well

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you haven't defined `operator==` for your `Attack` class. If you think about it, this is necessary. To remove an element from your vector that is equal to `to_rmv`, the algorithm needs to know how to test if two `Attack` objects are equal.

The simplest answer is to define `operator==` for `Attack`, eg:

```
// return true if x equals y, false otherwise
bool operator==(const Attack& x, const Attack& y)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

You might need to make this operator a `friend` of your `Attack` class.

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove()` uses `operator==` to compare the elements against the value you are wanting to remove.  If it is not defined for your class, then you should expect such an error.

Adding such an overload to `Attack` ought to suffice.  For example, using a simple `struct` for an `Attack`:

```
struct Attack {
    int attackId;
    int strength;
};

bool operator==(Attack const& a, Attack const& b) {
   return a.attackId == b.attackId && 
          a.strength == b.strength; 
}
```

Example on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/8dhrab